# Linear Difference Equations and how to solve for $y_n$

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

I am currently trying to study difference equations for my first year undergrad Calculus course. I am struggling to understand how they work. I am currently trying this question:

$y_{n+1}=y_{n}*((n+1)/n)$

I tried using back-substitution ie $y_n=y_{n-2}*((n+1)/n)^2$, to get $y_n=((n+1)/n)^n*y_0$ but my textbook says the correct answer is $y_n=An$

Can you please outline how I go about solving difference equations and explain why An is the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that your substitution isn't valid as $y_n = \frac{n}{n-1}y_{n-1}$

Comment: @Lost Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: The formula is $y_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{n}y_n$, correct? Notice that $\frac{n+1}{n}$ depends on the next term of the sequence.  It doesn't make sense to say that $y_2 = \frac{n+1}{n}y_1$ unless $n$ is constant, but this isn't the case here as $\frac{n+1}{n}$ corresponds with $y_{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{y_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{y_n}{n}$$ Let $$S_n=\frac{y_n}{n}$$ Then $$S_{n+1}=S_n=A$$ for some constant $A$, so $$y_n=nS_n=An$$

Or, note that the product telescopes: $$y_n=y_{n-1}\frac{n}{n-1}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n-2}y_{n-2}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n-2}\frac{n-2}{n-3}\cdots=An$$

Comment: can you explain the step $S_{n+1}=S_n=A$ please?

Comment: From the first equation, $S_{n+1}=S_n$. This means that all of $S$'s values are equal, so it must be equal to some constant number $A\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that, plugging in $n+1$ for $n$ in the definition of $S$, we get $$S_{n+1}=\frac{y_{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: is the answer $y_n=y_{1}*n$ equivalent?

Comment: @user127700 Yes that would also be correct.